# How to align text on elmentary label widget?

Tags: alignment, tizen, efl

I want align text to center on `elm_label` widget. I can't find any functions about text align as evas object text function or `elm_label` function. Also, I can't find a function that can get the text size (absolute pixel or relative size) on a label.

I have tried `elm_object_style_set` with `marker`, it was showed bold text on center of label, but font size was too small (smaller than default style). (and I don't want bold on text.)

How I can align text to the center of a label?

Comment: it's not question about qt widget. why you advise to read qt doc?
and also I can't find function on evas doc like setAlignment().

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake ;) I deleted it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add background to elementary(EFL) widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730499/how-to-add-background-to-elementaryefl-widget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML like markup to customize the way you want to the display the text in elm_label.

To align the text to the center, you can use `<align>` markup tag with value `center` .

```
std::string text = "<align = center> TEXT TO DISPLAY </align>";
Evas_Object *label = elm_label_add(parent);
elm_object_text_set(label,text.c_str());
evas_object_show(label);
```

You can also use other tags like `font_weight`, `font_style` to customize your display text. List of all possible tags can be found [here](http://docs.enlightenment.org/auto/eet/evas_textblock_style_page.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the alignment of the label through the `evas_object` API. Likely what you are looking for is:

```
evas_object_size_hint_align_set(label, 0.5, EVAS_HINT_FILL);
evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(label, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
```

The **0.5** is center, you could try **0.0** for left align and **1.0** for right.